# Select2 removing the wrong options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

So we are using a select2 input that utilizes remote data. It also allows the user to select multiple items.

I've run into an issue with select2 filtering out available options as the user selects items.

Let's take this set of remote data after the user types 'li':

```
[
{"text":"lions"},
{"text":"ligons"},
{"text":"live birds"},
{"text":"livers"}
]
```

They select an option (lets say 'lions') putting that object into the array of selected values.

Now the user searches for 'a' and the server returns:

```
[
{"text":"apple"},
{"text":"ants"},
{"text":"aaron"}
]
```

Now this is where the issue comes in. Select2 is trying to be helpful and skims the first object off the available choices because as far as it knows index 0 was already picked because 'lions' WAS in the index 0 spot. Now 'apples' is taken off the list because it's index 0.

If I make another choice, lets say ants, then the next search will skim 2 off the list (0 and 1).

How can I tell Select2 to compare the value of "text" when pulling available options out?

Comment: What version of Select2 are you using? That doesn't sound like what Select2 does when determining if an option has already been selected (hint: this is why you need an `id` usually).

Comment: @KevinBrown The actual data does have an id field and we are using 3.4.5

Comment: Select2 _should_ always compare to see if the item is selected based on the `id`, never based on the position in the list. Check to make sure that the `id` is unique, you might want to set it to the `text` if it isn't.